# How to DELETE the NEXT row values that is going to match the PREVIOUS row values base on a 2 column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help and I want to know, if how can I delete the next row or column values that matches the previous row or column values on a MySQL table base from a 2 columns.

So, if the next row/column values/result contains the same values on the previous rows/columns values/result it will be deleted, but if the next column didn't match both of the previous column values/result, that row should not be deleted. What will be the right query for that condition?

I'm trying to make a select query first, to verify the data and this is my query for the select. Is my query right for the select?

```sql
SELECT current_row.row, current_row.id, current_row.column1,
       current_row.column2, previous_row.row, previous_row.id,
       previous_row.column1, previous_row.column2 
FROM 
   (SELECT  @rownum:=@rownum+1 row, a.*    
    FROM MyTable a, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
    ORDER BY unix_time, id 
   ) as current_row 

LEFT JOIN  
   (SELECT @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 row, a.*    
    FROM MyTable a, (SELECT @rownum2:=0) r
   ORDER BY unix_time, id) as previous_row 

ON (current_row.id = previous_row.id) 
AND (current_row.column1 = previous_row.column1) 
AND (current_row.column2 = previous_row.column2) 
AND (current_row.row = previous_row.row - 1) 
LIMIT 10;
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Cheers!

Comment: Are there any hole and deleted `id`s in `mytable` ? Would you try to re-use this query over and over?

Comment: @MohaMad - Yes, basically this query needs to be run in a cron job or basically in a bash. But, I really need to know, how can I basically do that deletion.

Comment: @MohaMad - And by the way, NO deleted ID as of the moment.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry - So, what do you mean by providing this link? Do you find what I provided is not complete and verifiable example to cure the issue or give a right answer that I can use to? :)

Comment: @DatabaseAdmin The former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're trying to `select` data with assigned new virtual `id` for comparing, so `ON` clause should be `t1.myid=t2.myid+1` and `WHERE` clause should filter `col1` and `col2` rows:

```
 SET @id1:=0 , @id2:=0 ;
 SELECT * FROM (
      (SELECT *, @id1:=@id1+1 as myid from mytable ) as t1
 LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT *, @id2:=@id2+1 as myid from mytable ) as t2
 ON  t1.myid = t2.myid + 1
 )
 WHERE t1.col1= t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

And  for `DELETE` command, you should save results in temporary table and then delete rows where their id is stored in temp table:

```
 SET @id1:=0 , @id2:=0 ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_ids AS 
 SELECT t1.id FROM ( -- t1.id returns NEXT row
      (SELECT *, @id1:=@id1+1 as myid from mytable ) as t1
 LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT *, @id2:=@id2+1 as myid from mytable ) as t2
 ON  t1.myid = t2.myid + 1 -- t1.myid > t2.myid
 )
 WHERE t1.col1= t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 ;

 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id in (SELECT * FROM tbl_ids) ;
```

Comment: let me try if this works, so where can I have the deletion, by the way?

Comment: You like to delete previous row or next one? @DatabaseAdmin

Comment: if the next row/column values/result contains the same values on the previous rows/columns, that next values/result should be deleted, but if the next column didn't match both of the previous column values/result, that should not be deleted.

Comment: By the way, I got an error. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t1.col1= t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
 ) at line 1

Comment: Change `WHERE` line position as I've changed the code in answer. @DatabaseAdmin

Comment: at first, I removed the WHERE clause, but then do what you recommend, waiting for the result. And is the deletion part is on this? DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id in (SELECT * FROM tbl_ids) ; how?

Comment: The first code block in answer, just `select` all fields of duplicate rows in that way you described. The second code block is dangerous `DELETE` command. It find `id` and stores in tbl_ids and later deletes rows from main table where `id` is in `tbl_ids` table. @DatabaseAdmin

Comment: `WHERE id in (...)` is used to search id in array of numbers that returned from inner `SELECT` query in `(...)`.

Comment: Basically, select works perfectly I'll try the delete, as soon as my server can handle the load and I'll let you know. Thank you very much @Mohamad

Comment: In the absence of any ORDER BY clauses, this answer is meaningless.

Comment: Most of tables has auto increment id and asc sort, but you mention good subject. @strawberry

Comment: @MohaMad - the answer didn't meet what I needs to be deleted.

Comment: try adding `Order by id asc` in `(SELECT *, @id1:=@id1+1 as myid from mytable ) as t1` and `(SELECT *, @id2:=@id2+1 as myid from mytable ) as t2`